# How to wait for javascript promise to return value before continuing execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I have written a util class, which is a wrapper around promise based vendor library. My application will call this class (within App & Actions) to perform certain operations.

I am currently dealing with a scenario where my code needs to know the return value of promise within the Util class before proceeding to the next step. How can I do that?

The following is the tree structure of my code:

```
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── scripts
│   ├── vendor_script.min.js
├── src
│   ├── actions
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── common
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── WrapperAroundVendorScript_Utils.js
│   ├── components
│   │   └── app.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── reducers
│       └── index.js
├── style
│   └── style.css
├── webpack.config.js
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

Here, vendor_script.min.js is a vendor supplied JS library that uses JS promises to perform various actions. I have written a util class (WrapperAroundVendorScript_Utils.js) to abstract out the implementation details of vendor library.

> WrapperAroundVendorScript_Utils.js

```
let instance = null;

class VendorUtils {

  constructor (){

    const config = {
      some: value,
    }

    this._vendor = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.vendor ? window.vendor : require([PATH]);
    this._vendor.config = config;
  };

  static getInstance() {
    if(typeof instance == "undefined" || !instance){
      instance = new VendorUtils();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  doSomething(param1, param2) {
    this._vendor.domSomething(param1 + param2);
      .then(retVal => {
        return {retVal};
      });
  };

  doSomethingElse(param1, param2) {
    this._vendor.domSomethingElse(param1 + param2);
      .then(retVal => {
        return {retVal};
      });
  };
}

module.exports.VendorUtils = VendorUtils;
```

> app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {VendorUtils} from '../common/js/VendorUtils';

export default class App extends Component {

  clicked(){
    let utilsInstance = VendorUtils.getInstance();
    let x = utilsInstance.doSomething('a','b');
    let y = utilsInstance.doSomethingElse(x,'a');
    // call action with values received in previous steps
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.clicked}>Click Me!</button>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.clicked}>Click Me!</button>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.clicked}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PS: I need such synchronous behavior because there are multiple child/nested/sub components within the class that will be calling such common functions.

Comment: `.then` not working for you?

Comment: @Sag1v `.then` would create a promise that would evaluate whenever it gets to execute but by that time the calling function has already moved on to the next line of code. So, value of x would be undefined.

Comment: the next line / lines that needs the value should be inside the `.then` block. you could use async / await but thats just promises and generators behind the scene.

Comment: @RahilParikh It's impossible to do without creating a chain of promises. You cannot block until a promise resolves, you can only put *all* the code that should execute later in a `then` callback (or after an `await`)

Comment: @Bergi Wouldn't that destroy the purpose of abstraction functions? Because, now, I will be forced to put the low level logic into high level code (unless I am missing something obvious).

Comment: @RahilParikh: The thing you're missing is, as soon as your function does some asynchronous work with promises, then anything that uses that function also must be asynchronous. You can't mix sync and async

Comment: @RahilParikh The only abstraction you can do over asynchronous vs synchronous is to make everything asynchronous. Not sure I understand what you mean by "*low level logic*" and "*high level code*".

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of where you would want to use `async`/`await`

```
async clicked() {
  const utilsInstance = VendorUtils.getInstance();
  const x = await utilsInstance.doSomething('a','b');
  const y = await utilsInstance.doSomethingElse(x,'a');
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution that you suggested but when I put `console.log` statements in `clicked` and `doSomething`, I noticed that JavaScript first prints value of `x` from `clicked` (which is `undefined`) and then prints the returns the value `retVal` from `doSomething` (which is `ab`). Please note that the code within `.then` is a long running task that can sometimes take upto 4/5 seconds.

Comment: @RahilParikh you get `undefined` because you still missing the most important point of the problem, you are awaiting of undefined, because you don't return promise in your do something functions, please see my answer.

Comment: @RahilParikh as mentioned by Nik, you don't appear to be returning a promise from inside your `doSomething` functions. Fix those calls and you'll find this code works as expected.

Comment: This, by itself, is not enough.  The OP has to fix their `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` methods to work properly too.

Comment: @jfriend00 already pointed that out in the comments, the question was more about how to use the result of one promise in a subsequent one.

Comment: Yeah, but without fixing `doSomething()` to properly return a promise, the `await` doesn't do what the OP wants.  The OP clearly doesn't understand that part either.

Answer (score 0):

You can either execute the code you want to wait inside the `then` clause of you promoise, or you could use the `async / await` feature of Javascript.

A detailed guide with examples can be found [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/).

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your doSomething functions:

```
doSomething(param1, param2) {
  this._vendor.domSomething(param1 + param2);
    .then(retVal => {
      return {retVal};
    });
};
```

1. There should be no semicolon ";" before ".then" method.
2. Your do something functions should return promises, you can not return a value from a "then" block.

Consider to change your do something functions a bit:

```
doSomething(param1, param2) {
  // return the promise
  return this._vendor.domSomething(param1 + param2)
    // maybe you don't need this part at all if you want to get only the value instead of {retVal: value} object
    .then(retVal => {
      // if you do async operations here make sure you returned a new
      //   promise here instead of object, in that case you would need
      //   another .then block to process internal promise that you 
      //   would create inside this .then block 
      return {retVal};
    });
};
```

that way, inside your async "clicked" function you would be able to use await for returned promises:

```
async clicked() {
  let utilsInstance = VendorUtils.getInstance();

  // you can check what doSomething returns here - it would be a promise
  let doSomethingPromise = utilsInstance.doSomething('a','b');

  // await a previously saved promise to get a value
  let x = await doSomethingPromise;

  // obviously you still can await promise in one sentence
  let y = await utilsInstance.doSomethingElse(x,'a');

  // call action with values received in previous steps
}
```